# Move to the first empty column

Tags: excel, vba, offset

This code searches for a string, moves to the left using Ctrl Left, and then one more to the left.  that is what the offset command is for.  but it gives an error.
Can't figure out why. Should probably say that there are some hidden columns in the spreadsheet.

```
Sub delete_column()
    Cells.Find(What:="Transcript - Curriculum Title (Transcript)", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext _
        , MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End Sub
```

Comment: If `Selection.End(xlToLeft)` is on Col A, there is no space for `one more to the left`. `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)` raises the error.

Comment: Please have a look at [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).  You should also fully qualify your reference to `Cells` otherwise it will use the `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback  @Darren Bartrup-Cook but it does not solve my problem

Comment: No, true it doesn't solve your problem.  But it will help you write more robust code that's less likely to fail based on what cell/sheet is selected before the code is executed.